# What is a parallel session in PKCS#11

Tags: pkcs11

I have seen in the [PKCS#11 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html#_Toc416959715) that "parallel sessions" are not supported

```
"in Cryptoki Version 2.01 and up, no token supports parallel sessions"
```

but I can also see that a token may have multiple sessions open with the same token because ulMaxSessionCount is defined as (the)

```
"maximum number of sessions that can be opened with the token at one time by a single application"
```

What is meant by "parallel session" if not multiple sessions on the same token?

Comment: I believe it has to do with serial or parallel communication. This has not to do with multiple sessions on multiple threads, but with the hardware configuration used to communicate. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_communication and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_communication The reason I think so is because CKF_SERIAL_SESSION is always true.